# How do I add auth headers to axios hooks requests?

Tags: axios, react-hooks

I am working with React Hooks and I want to use the axios hooks package to send an image to Cloudinary.

```
const [ 
    { data: putData, loading: putLoading, error: putError },
    executePut
  ] = useAxios(
    {
      url: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/820fc',
      method: 'PUT'
    },
    { manual: true }
  )
```

The docs say nothing about headers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you are looking for this:

```
const [ 
    { data: putData, loading: putLoading, error: putError },
    executePut
  ] = useAxios(
    {
      url: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/820fc',
      method: 'PUT',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    },
    { manual: true }
  )
```

docs: https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config